# ++ is deprecated - "+= 1 is not solving the issue"

Tags: deprecated, array-merge, swift2

After updating Xcode to 7.3 I am having some warnings saying :

> '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3

The code where the warning appear is a function that merges two arrays:

```
arr4.append(arr1[i++])
```

I have tried changing it with :

`arr4.append(arr1[i += 1])`

but I get an error saying :

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String]]' with an index of type
>   '()'

The full code is:

```
let arr1 = [["aaa","111"],["bbb","222"],["ccc","333"]]
let arr2 = [["ddd","444"],["eee","555"],["fff","666"]]

var arr4 = zip(arr1, arr2).reduce([]) { ( newArr, p:(Array<String>, Array<String>)) -> [[String]] in

    var arr = newArr

    arr.append(p.0)
    arr.append(p.1)
    return arr
}

var i = arr4.count / 2
while i < arr1.count {
    arr4.append(arr1[i++]) // WARNING
}

while i < arr2.count {
    arr4.append(arr2[i++]) // WARNING
}
print(arr4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
arr4.append(arr1[i])
i += 1
```

The motivation for the change is legibility — ensuring that steps are properly spelt out, reducing ambiguity. The result of the expression `a += 1` is of type `void` — it does something, but doesn't evaluate to anything — which is expressed as the empty tuple, `()`, and cannot be used as an array index.

(Aside: `+= 1` also isn't a direct substitution for `++` in C.

```
    int a = 3;
    int b = a += 1;
    NSLog(@"%d %d", a, b);
```

... will produce a different output than the equivalent `b = a ++;`.)

Comment: in c++ and objective c. a += 1 returns a value. is your answer specific for swift?

Comment: Yes. Swift-tagged question so Swift answer. With omitted semicolons and everything. The mention of C is then sandboxed into an aside, and explicitly mentioned as such — with the included `NSLog` also being a clue that the most likely Swift audience would pick up.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
arr4.append(arr1[i])
i += 1
```

If you insist to do it in a single line. you can but it looks ugly:

```
arr4.append(arr1[(i += 1) - 1])
```

I not sure. test it.